# logo on top of image in div not responsive

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive, styled-components

I have a div container that has a div as background image and an img tag as a logo to over lap the background image.

signin,jsx

```
const SignIn = () => (
<div style={{display:'flex'}}>
  <div style={{flex:2}}>
    <ImageDiv bg={signin} src = {signin} alt="logo" />
    <LogoDiv src={logo} alt="logo" />
  </div>
```

Imagediv.jsx

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const ImageDiv = styled.div`
  background-image: url(${(props) => props.bg}), url(${(props) => props.bg}); 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
  background-size: cover;
`
export default ImageDiv;
```

logoDiv.jsx

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const LogoDiv = styled.img`
src: url(${(props) => props.bg});
width: 200px;
height: 108px;
position: absolute;
left: 175px;
right: 175px;
bottom: 106px;
z-index: 1;
`;

export default LogoDiv;
```

Ill attach the screens when its large and small and a clear difference is shown, I need help on how to fix that the logo remains in the lower middle of the div even if the screen gets smaller[image: Large screen]

[image: Smaller screen size]

Comment: This is more of a css problem than react, it'll be easier to debug if you'd put up a code snippet with only the css/html

Comment: I used styled-components for css, so all css used is already attached

Comment: You can use flexbox to solve that easily. Use `display:flex` and `align-items:center` for the div that contains the logo.

Comment: @SImonHaddad after you run your code you can extract the css from devtools

Answer (score 0):

Use justify-content: center;   where display:flex is applied. so logo will remain in center position.